# stm32l152 as I2C slave not acknowledging address

Tags: i2c, slave, stm32l152

Im using two stm32l152 discovery boars. One is configured as master and the other as slave. I have acknowladge enabled on both of them, but when the master sends the address the slave doesn't send the ack bit at the 9 clock pulse. The ports are set to alternate function 4 and to open drain. I am using external 4.7k pullup resistors to 3.3V. I've checked all the registers multiple times and I don't know why the slave doesn't recognizes it's address.

[This is the output from the logic analyser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D46hX.jpg)

D3 is the start bit from the master
D4 is the addres matched bit on the slave.
This is the slave code:

```
#define USE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER
#include "stm32l1xx.h"
#include "stm32l1xx_conf.h"

//Quick hack, approximately 1ms delay
void ms_delay(int ms)
{
    while (ms> 0) {
        volatile int x = 5971;
        while (x> 0) {
            x--;
        }
        ms--;
    }
}
#define SCL 8
#define SDA 9

int main(void)
{
    RCC->AHBENR |= (0x1 << 1);

    //set port to alternate function
    GPIOB->MODER &= ~((0x3 << (2 * SCL)) | (0x3 << (2 * SDA)) | (0x3 << (2 * 5)));
    GPIOB->MODER |= ((0x2 << (2 * SCL)) | (0x2 << (2 * SDA)) | (0x1 << (2 * 5)));

    GPIOB->OTYPER |= ((1 << SCL) | (1 << SDA)); //set output PB6 and PB7 to open drain

    //set PB6 and PB7 to no pullup no pulldown
    GPIOB->PUPDR &= ~((0x3 << (2 * SCL)) | (0x3 << (2 * SDA)) | (0x3 << (2 * 5))); 

    //set PB6 and PB7 to alternate function 4(I2C)
    GPIOB->AFR[1] &= ~((0b1111 << (4 * 0)) | (0b1111 << (4 * 1)));
    //set PB6 and PB7 to alternate function 4(I2C)
    GPIOB->AFR[1] |= ((0b0100 << (4 * 0)) | (0b0100 << (4 * 1)));

    RCC->APB1ENR |= (1 << 21);

    //reset I2C
    I2C1->CR1 |= (1 << 15);
    ms_delay(1);
    I2C1->CR1 &= ~(1 << 15);

    I2C1->CR2 |= 0b001000; //peripheral clock set to 8MHz
    I2C1->CR1 |= (1 << 10); //ACK enabled

    I2C1->OAR1 |= (0x05 << 1); //setting primary address

    I2C1->CR1 |= 1; //I2C peripheral enabled when configuration is done

    for (;;) {
        if ((I2C1->SR1&(1 << 1)) != 0) {
            GPIOB->ODR |= (1 << 5);
        }
        else {
            GPIOB->ODR &= ~(1 << 5);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the master code:

```
#define USE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER
#include "stm32l1xx.h"
#include "stm32l1xx_conf.h"

#define SCL 8
#define SDA 9

int main(void)
{
    RCC->AHBENR |= (0x1 << 1);

    //set port to alternate function
    GPIOB->MODER &= ~((0x3 << (2 * SCL)) | (0x3 << (2 * SDA)) | (0x3 << (2 * 5)));
    GPIOB->MODER |= ((0x2 << (2 * SCL)) | (0x2 << (2 * SDA)) | (0x1 << (2 * 5)));

    //set output PB6 and PB7 to open drain
    GPIOB->OTYPER |= ((1 << SCL) | (1 << SDA));
    //set PB6 and PB7 to no pullup no pulldown
    GPIOB->PUPDR &= ~((0x3 << (2 * SCL)) | (0x3 << (2 * SDA)) | (0x3 << (2 * 5)));

    //set PB6 and PB7 to alternate function 4(I2C)
    GPIOB->AFR[1] &= ~((0b1111 << (4 * 0)) | (0b1111 << (4 * 1)));
    //set PB6 and PB7 to alternate function 4(I2C)
    GPIOB->AFR[1] |= ((0b0100 << (4 * 0)) | (0b0100 << (4 * 1)));

    I2C1->CR1 |= (1 << 15);
    I2C1->CR1 &= ~(1 << 15);

    RCC->APB1ENR |= (1 << 21);

    I2C1->CR2 |= 0x08; //peripheral clock set to 8MHz
    I2C1->CCR |= 0x28; //
    I2C1->TRISE |= 0x09;
    I2C1->CR1 |= (1 << 10); //ACK enabled

    I2C1->CR1 |= 1; //I2C peripheral enabled when configuration is done
    I2C1->CR1 |= (1 << 8); //generate start condition (master mode)

    for (;;) {
        //check start condition
        if ((I2C1->SR1&(1 << 0)) != 0) {
            GPIOB->ODR |= (1 << 5);
            I2C1->DR = 0x0b << 0; //send slave addres
        }
        else {
            GPIOB->ODR &= ~(1 << 5);
        }

        if ((I2C1->SR1&(1 << 1)) != 0) {
            GPIOB->ODR |= (1 << 5);
        }
        else {
            GPIOB->ODR &= ~(1 << 5);
        }
    }
}
```

Im compiling with arm-none-eabi-gcc and using the stsw-stm32077 librarys from stm

Comment: Do both boards have the same common?  And... that's the extent of my advice, you might have better luck posting this at [https://electronics.stackexchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Yes they have a common ground. I've messured all the connections again and they are all ok. I think there is a problem in the software probably a register is not set correctly but i don't know which one

Comment: By the way you define #define SCL 8
#define SDA 9 like that.But you said (set output PB6 and PB7 to open drain) in all your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code is that you have to set the ack bit after the peripheral is enabled, if you do it before, the ack bit gets automatically reset.